# Custom ListView throwing IndexOutOfBound

Tags: android, listview, indexoutofboundsexception, separator

I'm making a custom ListView in which I want to display details with a separator.  I have almost achieved it but now it is throwing IndexOutOfBoundException whenever I reach the end of the list and isn't managing the separator properly. I tried to add the screenshot to give a proper idea but I ain't that popular yet.

Check this out. Can you point out my mistake(s). Thanks!

**LogCat**:

```
07-21 21:03:36.597: E/(31016): file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 10
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at com.example.contactlist.MainActivity$MyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:103)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2292)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2030)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:822)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:786)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5272)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4422)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:766)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:575)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:541)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:751)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
07-21 21:03:42.762: E/AndroidRuntime(31016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**MainActivity**:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    in = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Contacts = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();

    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("FBC", "1111111111", "#88",
            "ABC@.com"));
    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("DEF", "2222222222", "#775",
            "DEF@.com"));
    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("EEHI", "3333333333", "#876",
            "HHH@.com"));
    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("AAAKL", "5555555555", "#443",
            "MAK@.com"));
    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("MNO", "4444444444", "#112",
            "HULK@.com"));
    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("BBCC", "666133111", "#828",
            "BBCC@.com"));
    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("CCCDEF", "5778322222", "#7175",
            "DDCCCEF@.com"));
    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("IIoI", "9877445333", "#8176",
            "IIoI@.com"));
    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("QYYKL", "4444442355", "#4143",
            "QQYYAK@.com"));
    Contacts.add(new ContactInfo("JJKNO", "7786565444", "#1122",
            "JJKKL@.com"));

    Collections.sort(Contacts, new VideoComparator());

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView title;
    TextView number;
    TextView address;
    TextView email;
    ImageView image;
}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ViewHolder holder;

    public MyAdapter() {

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (ConvertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            ConvertView = in.inflate(R.layout.list_components, parent,false);
            holder.name = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.number = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            holder.email = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
            holder.address = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            holder.image = (ImageView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.Contact_Image);
            holder.title = (TextView) ConvertView.findViewById(R.id.Alphabet);

            ConvertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) ConvertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(Contacts.get(position).getName());
        holder.number.setText(Contacts.get(position).getNumber());
        holder.email.setText(Contacts.get(position).getEmail());
        holder.address.setText(Contacts.get(position).getAddress());

        char Name1 = Contacts.get(position).getName().charAt(0);
        char Name2 = Contacts.get(position+1).getName().charAt(0);

        if(position==0)
        {
            holder.title.setText("A");
        }
        else if(!(Name1 == Name2))
        {

            holder.title.setText(Name2);
        }

        return ConvertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Contacts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `getView` method you try to access an element that's not in the `Contacts` list.

`char Name2 = Contacts.get(position+1).getName().charAt(0);`

`position+1` would `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the last element of the list is rendered.

Comment: So how can I rectify that? I need to compare the two consecutive elements and if the value changes, I need to put a separator in between them.

Comment: @MurdocN I'd pre-process the contacts list and put separator entries right on the data collection. Then I'd have the adapter serve two view types: one for a contact entry and another for a separator. Look at getViewTypeCount & getViewType methods on BaseAdapter.

Comment: The problem has been solved, brother. I posted the way I accomplished it. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`char Name2 = Contacts.get(position+1).getName().charAt(0);`

You are looking for the next `Contact`, and when you reach the end of the list, this will produce an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is this Line:

```
char Name2 = Contacts.get(position+1).getName().charAt(0);
```

Validate this line with

```
if (position < Contacts.size()) {
           char Name2 = Contacts.get(position+1).getName().charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: This happened because if you have 10 elements, the cycle when is in the element 10, you are trying adding a 1 unit to counter, so the code are searching the element 11, but you don't have a array with 11 elements, so for that is the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: IndexOutOfBound is still there. :/

Answer (score 0):

I finally **solved** the problem.

```
    if(position>0 && position < Contacts.size()){
            char c1 = Contacts.get(position-1).getName().charAt(0);
            char c2 = Contacts.get(position).getName().charAt(0);

            if(c1 == c2){
                holder.title.setText("");
            }else{
                holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(c2));
            }
        }
```